# How to work with mutliple window in selenium IDE

Tags: testing, automation, selenium-ide

I am trying automate simple feature , when user clicks on button a new windows opens and user can perform actions on the new window. Can anyone help here . After executing the code its get failed at
click on id=cell-2-undefined Failed:
18:25:50
Exceeded waiting time for new window to appear 2000ms

```
open | https://test.com // 
setWindowSize | 1280x672
click | id=cell-2-undefined (When user click here a new window opens .
waitForNewWindow | 3000
selectWindow | handle=${win7830}
mouseOver | id=mui-p-14634-T-2
click | id=mui-p-14634-T-2 
mouseOut | tag=body
```